# How can I save a SparseArray in a Room database?

Tags: android-room, android-sparsearray

I'm trying to persist a SparseArray in a Room database and can not get it to compile. I keep getting the "Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type" error message along with "The query returns some columns [plannerLineData] which are not use by android.util.SparseArray."

I have tried using a single field in the PlannerLine Entity alone with a separate PlannerLineData class.

I have data converters to convert SparseArray to String and to convert String back to SparseArray.

I have checked several questions on stackoverflow and have successfully used the Date to Long and the Long to Date converters in other projects, but I seem to be missing something somewhere.

Data Files:

```
@Entity
public class PlannerLine implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@TypeConverters(Converters.class)
@PrimaryKey
@SerializedName("planner_line")
@NonNull
public SparseArray plannerLineData;

public SparseArray getPlannerLineData() {
    return plannerLineData;
}

public void setPlannerLineData(SparseArray plannerLineData) {
    this.plannerLineData = plannerLineData;
}


public class PlannerLineData implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("lineId")
public int lineId;

@SerializedName("plan_text")
public String planText;

public int getLineId() {
    return lineId;
}

public void setLineId(int lineId) {
    this.lineId = lineId;
}

public String getPlanText() {
    return planText;
}

public void setPlanText(String planText) {
    this.planText = planText;
}
```

}

DAO problem area:

```
@Dao
public interface PlannerDao {

@Query("SELECT * from PlannerLine")  
public SparseArray getPlannerLine();  <---Doesn't like this line
```

I have also tried returning `SparseArray<PlannerLine>` and `SparseArray<PlannerLineData>`, but no joy.

Converters class:

```
public class Converters {

@TypeConverter
public static String sparseArrayToString(SparseArray sparseArray) {
    if (sparseArray == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int size = sparseArray.size();
    if (size <= 0) {
        return "{}";
    }

    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(size * 28);
    buffer.append('{');
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            buffer.append("-,- ");
        }
        int key = sparseArray.keyAt(i);
        buffer.append(key);
        buffer.append("-=-");
        Object value = sparseArray.valueAt(i);
        buffer.append(value);
    }
    buffer.append('}');
    return buffer.toString();

}

@TypeConverter
public static SparseArray stringToSparseArray(String string) {
    if (string == null) {
        return null;
    }

    String entrySeparator = "-=-";
    String elementSeparator = "-,-";
    SparseArray sparseArray = new SparseArray();

    String[] entries = StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator(string, elementSeparator);
    for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        String[] parts = StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator(entries[i], entrySeparator);
        int key = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        String text = parts[1];
        sparseArray.append(key, text);
    }
    return sparseArray;
}
```

Suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks

Edit:

My original vision for this app was to store all the plan lines in a single `SparseArray`, along with two additional `SparseIntArrays` (which I did not mention before because the solution would be similar to the `SparseArray`) to hold info on how the plan lines interact with each other.

After reading through @dglozano's helpful responses, I have decided to re-design the app to just store regular DB files in Room and load the data into the `SparseArray` (and the two `SparseIntArrays`) at startup, use only the in memory `SparseArray` and `SparseIntArrays` while the app is active, then write changes in the Sparse Arrays to the DB during `onStop()`. I am also considering updating the DB in the background as I work through app.

Because the answers and suggestions provided by @dglozano led me to the re-design decision, I am accepting his answer as the solution.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are doing the Conversion properly. However, the problem is in your DAO Query:

```
@Query("SELECT * from PlannerLine")  // This returns a List of PlannerLine, not a SparseArray
public SparseArray getPlannerLine(); // The return type is SparseArray, not a List of PlannerLine
```

Therefore, you can try two different things:

1 - Change the Query to `@Query("SELECT plannerLineData FROM PlannerLine WHERE lineId == :lineId")` , so that the query returns the `SparseArray` inside the `PlannerLine` with id `lineId`. You should change the method signature so it accepts the parameter `lineId`

```
@Query("SELECT plannerLineData FROM PlannerLine WHERE lineId == :lineId")
public SparseArray getPlannerLine(int lineId);
```

2 -  If you want to return the full `PlannerLine` object and then access to its `SparseArray` field, then you should change the return type. You should also add the `lineId` parameter to return just one record and not a list of all the `PlannerLine` stored in the database table.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM PlannerLine WHERE lineId == :lineId")
public PlannerLine getPlannerLine(int lineId);
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to get a `List<PlannerLine>` with all the `PlannerLine` stored in the database, use the following query in your Dao.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM PlannerLine")
public List<PlannerLine> getAllPlannerLines();
```

Then you can access to the SparseArray of each PlannerLine in the list as usual.

Comment: Your first comment about the query returning a List of PlannerLine is helpful and helps me see the problem.  What I was hoping to get was the entire SparseArray with all it's elements at app startup.  Perhaps a variation of your option 1 without the WHERE, or possibly get a List of all the PlannerLine during startup then fill the SparseArray manually.  I will try out a few more things in the next few days.  Thanks.

Comment: If you want to get all the PlannerLine stored in the database table with their corresponding SparseArray, simple use the query I put in my updated answers. If it helps, please upvote and accept :) Cheers, Diego.

Comment: @mtdavem I am glad to hear that you managed to solve it. Happy coding!